Diagnostic settings can't be added to "storageAccounts/blobServices" from ARM templates
Diagnostic settings can't be added to "storageAccounts/blobServices" from ARM templates.
I got the below error when I deployed diagnostic settings from ARM templates.
Does anyone know hoe to solve this?
*I cannot use bicep due to company rules.
Error Message
{"code":"OperationNotFound","message":"Path: '/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storageName}/blobServices/default/providers/Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/{storageName}-sa-blob-logs' is not supported"}

ARM template
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings",
            "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('StorageName'), '-sa-blob-logs')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "scope": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices', variables('StorageName'), 'default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices', variables('StorageName'), 'default')]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "workspaceId": "[resourceId(variables('subscriptionId'), variables('OtherResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', variables('logAnalyticsWorkSpaceName')]",
                "logs": [
                    {
                        "category": "StorageWrite",
                        "enabled": true
                    }
                ],
                "metrics": [
                    {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "timeGrain": "PT1M"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

Any answer would be helped. Thank you.

Are you looking for only an ARM template, or are PowerShell or CLI scripts also acceptable?

Thank you for asking, I am looking for only an ARM template.

I hope this helps to resolve your issue.

The above error was encountered due to incorrect resource ID format  when trying to deploy diagnostic settings specifically to blobServices.
Here is the updated ARM template to create a diagnostic settings for storage accounts blob service with the latest API version: 2021-05-01-preview, Follow Ms Doc for more details about latest API version.
{
    {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "storageAccountName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "venkatstoragedemo"
      },
      "settingName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "storagelogs"
      },
      "subscriptionId": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "SUB_ID"
      },
      "resourceGroupName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "venkat-rg"
      },
      "logAnalyticsWorkSpaceName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "venkat-law"
      }
    },
    "variables": {
      "LogworkspaceResoueceId": "[resourceId(parameters('subscriptionId'), parameters('resourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', parameters('logAnalyticsWorkSpaceName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings",
        "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
        "scope": "[format('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{0}/blobServices/default', parameters('storageAccountName'))]",
        "name": "[parameters('settingName')]",
        "properties": {
          "workspaceId": "[variables('LogworkspaceResoueceId')]",
          "metrics": [
            {
              "category": "Transaction",
              "enabled": true,
              "timeGrain": "PT1M"
            }
          ],
          "logs": [
            {
              "category": "StorageWrite",
              "enabled": true
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }

Output
az deployment group create --resource-group "venkat-rg" --template-file "Storage.json"


After running the code, the diagnostic settings have been created for the storage account blob.


